# MYSQL SQL Statement which insert many rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, sql-insert

I want to put contents to notice Database user level > 1;

so I tried this Statement

```
insert into test4 (id, content) values (
    (select user_id from account where user_rank>=0), 
    'alert'
);
```

But it keep saying Subquery returns more than 1 row.

Is it impossible to put many rows in one statement?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`values()` expects a tuple of values that represent just one row, but your subquery returns multiple rows, hence the error that you are getting.

Instead, you can use the [`insert ... select` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html), with a fixed literal value as second column:

```
insert into test4 (id, content)
select user_id, 'alert' from account where user_rank > °
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO test4 (id, content)
VALUES SELECT user_id, 'alert' FROM account WHERE user_rank >= 0;
```